# How to convert a .ui file to .py file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

This .ui file is made by Qt Designer. It's just a simple UI.

All the commands or codes for doing this on the websites I have looked through are not for windows.

Comment: Say, pyuic4 -o ui_form.py form.ui doesn't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The pyuic tool works in exactly the same way on all platforms:

```
C:\>pyuic4 -h
Usage: pyuic4 [options] <ui-file>

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p, --preview         show a preview of the UI instead of generating code
  -o FILE, --output=FILE
                        write generated code to FILE instead of stdout
  -x, --execute         generate extra code to test and display the class
  -d, --debug           show debug output
  -i N, --indent=N      set indent width to N spaces, tab if N is 0 [default: 4]
  -w, --pyqt3-wrapper   generate a PyQt v3 style wrapper

  Code generation options:
    --from-imports      generate imports relative to '.'
    --resource-suffix=SUFFIX
                        append SUFFIX to the basename of resource files
                        [default: _rc]
```

I suspect the reason "it doesn't work" is that the .ui file you are trying to convert is not in the current directory. So you need to cd to that directory first:

```
    C:\>cd C:\path\to\my\ui\files
```

then run pyuic:

```
    C:\path\to\my\ui\files\>pyuic4 -o ui_form.py form.ui
```

Answer (score 19):

In pyqt5 you can use:

1. convert to none-executable python file :

   pyuic5 -o pyfilename.py design.ui
2. convert to executable python file :

   pyuic5 -x -o pyfilename.py design.ui

and also for resource diles(qrc):

1. convert `qrc` to python file :

   pyrcc5 -o pyfilename.py res.qrc

`Note:` that if you run the command in the wrong way,your `ui` file will be lost.So you have to make a copy of your files:)

Comment: That's perfect solution

Answer (score 15):

To convert from `.ui` to `.py` in Windows

1. Go to the directory where your `ui` file is.
2. Press shift right-click your mouse.
3. Click `open command window here`.
4. This will open the `cmd`, check what is the directory of your
   `(pyuic4.bat) file`. Usually, it is in:
   `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat`.
5. Write in the `cmd`:
   `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat -x filename.ui -o filename.py`   (hit Enter)
   this will generate a new file `.py` for your `.ui` file
   and in the same directory

Note:
This command for Python 3.4 version and PyQt4 version.
If you are using other versions you should change the numbers (e.g PyQt5)

Answer (score 7):

Better Late Than Never, create a batch file on windows (.bat) and paste the following into it , save & run from the same directory as your files.

```
@echo off
title .UI to .py files converter !
echo Generate Python files from .UI files!
pause
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo UI file Name
set /p UiName=Enter .UI file Name: 
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo PY file Name
set /p PyName=Enter .PY file Name: 
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo Start Converting Files Please wait.



call python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x "%UiName%" -o "%PyName%"

echo QRC file Name
set /p QrName=Enter .qrc file Name: 
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo PY file Name
set /p PiName=Enter .PY file Name: 
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo Start Converting Files Please wait.

pyrcc5 -o "%PiName%" "%QrName%"

echo Job Completed.
pause
```