# How to solve : "No resource in resource descprition" in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, python-3.8, file-conversion

I am trying to automatically convert Qt designer files with `.ui` extensions to `.py` file in`Pycharm` using an external tool created with `Pyrcc5.exe` script. The arguments are:

`$FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.py`

After executing the `.ui` file with the external tool that I created I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

The external tool named `Pyuic` and it's details are here:

[image: Pyuic External Tool]

I don't want to manually convert each .ui file into .py and then put it into the project directory. A solution to this error would be appreciated.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266802/how-to-convert-a-ui-file-to-py-file

Comment: @UmairMubeen The solution is for the console commands, however I tried the argument, it still doesn't work in Pycharm while using the external tool.

Comment: why dont use used pyqt user interface tool it will help you ton convert .ui file into py

Comment: @UmairMubeen I have clearly mentioned the reason as to why I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have found a very simple solution to this.

Just replace the `Pyrcc5.exe with Pyuic5.exe` and the put the arguments as this:

`-x $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.py`

Comment: Instead of converting each .ui file to .py file is not suggestive for a large scale project. A better alternative I am using right now is to load the UI file from a different .py and use it there.